# How do weather changes work during battle?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet

Sometimes the weather can change during Pokemon battles in ways that impact the fight. What determines how the weather changes during battle? Does the weather change in real time like in the overworld or is it based on the number of turns that has passed?